# Magento2 - Admin grid Filter tab always show active

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, admin, grid, filter

How to make admin panel grid filter on all the page. Tab always show active.

Like a shared screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution

Created admin theme and override the filters.html

```
/app/design/adminhtml/<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Ui/web/templates/grid/filters.html
```

removed `$collapsible.opened()` function from file. so the filter will always appear

> css="_active: hasVisible() && $collapsible.opened()"

to

> css="_active: hasVisible()"

Answer (score 0):

in *app/design/adminhtml///Magento_Ui/web/templates/grid/filters/filters.html*

```
<div class="data-grid-filters-actions-wrap" collapsible="openClass: false, closeOnOuter: false, opened:true">
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="data-grid-filters-actions-wrap" collapsible="openClass: false, closeOnOuter: false,opened:true">

Comment: Hi Ajay, thank you for your contribution. Answers do better if you give a bit more detail in your explanation. Try to add more text explaining what you did there